# RMI NotSerializableException class extend thread and UnicastRemoteObject

Tags: java, multithreading, interface, rmi

I have a class that is extended to thread that is implementing an interface that is used for RMI connection. the issue is that I have to extend the UnicastRemoteObject not know how to coordinate the two extends. Wanted each class implements this thread up later with one interface to the RMI server to get callback.
Basically, I wanted a class extend thread implements a callback interface for the purpose.
Any idea?

Example

```
class Test extends Thread implements Interface
{

(..)
}
```

But for the proper functioning extends UnicastRemoteObject should do, but have no logic as to extend thread, UnicastRemoteObject. I do not know how to do...
Because if you do not extend the exception java.io.NotSerializableException will receive:

Thank you for your attention

Comment: Your question seems to be like a riddle for us to figure out what the question is. I think you need to be more clear to get a better answer

Comment: Clean up your code. There is never a reason for a particular class to extend `Thread`. There’s always a way to achieve the same without subclassing it. Have a look at the constructors of `Thread` which accept a `Runnable`.

Comment: Solved by changing the code so that it is not necessary to extend the thread class implements an interface....

Answer (score 0):

> the issue is that I have to extend the UnicastRemoteObject

No it isn't. You don't have to extend `UnicastRemoteObject.` You can just implement the remote interface and call `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()` to export the remote object.